# C instructions not executed in order

Tags: c

I'm a real newbie in C but I'm willing to learn a lot, and I have written this very simple program, in which the user is asked to type a number with the keyboard. Before that, the message "Please type a real number with the keyboard" should be displayed, and after, a message confirming to the user the value of the number they typed. *(code below)*

The problem is, when I build my executable and then run it, it first asks for the value of x, and displays the message "Please type a real number with the keyboard" only **after** the user typed a number! What did I do wrong? 
Could someone explain me this weird behaviour, since I typed my instructions in the good order?

```
#include <stdio.h> /* package to read and to write variables */

int main(void) /* main program */
{
    float x; /* declaring a real number x*/

    printf("Please type a real number with the keyboard\n");
    scanf("%f", &x); /* prompting x with the keyboard */
    /* displaying x : */
    printf("You just typed %f, congratulations !", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you run this program?

Comment: We'll need to know what platform you're running this on: what is the OS and the exact compiler version you're compiling with?

Comment: It might help to explain what flags you're compiling with too.  FWIW, I see no issues with the code you've given.  And the C compiler generally doesn't not re-order function calls, so something smells pretty fishy.

Comment: my OS is Windows 10 64-bit. And my compiler is MinGW 4.9.3.

Comment: How are you running the program? From the console or from some IDE?

Comment: It looks like `stdout` is being cached more than expected. It should not happen unless there is something broken. Try calling `fflush(stdout)` just after the `printf()` to see if it improves.

Comment: I would normally expect your prompt to appear before the `scanf` is executed, because the prompt ends in a newline `\n` character and `stdout` is normally line buffered.  If that is not the case for some reason, you can easily force it to be flushed by adding `fflush(stdout);` immediately before the call to `scanf`.

Comment: Does it work if you do `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`? It should flush because of the new line but worth a shot?

Comment: Thank you guys, adding `fflush(stdout)` after the first line worked!

Comment: and @EugeneSh. I am running the program from the console (I am using Eclipse). First I build it, and then I run it. Is it the way it's supposed to be?

What does "line buffered" mean?

Comment: this is what I though. Eclipse's console has this trouble with buffered output. It's a bug in Eclipse. Try running the executable from command line, it will behave correctly

Comment: OK thank you very much, I will remove the `fflush` instruction and see if it works if I run the program externally

Comment: @EugeneSh., as initially opened, the standard input and output are fully buffered "if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device" (C2011, 7.21.3/7), and "what constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined" (C2011, 5.1.2.3/7), so I think it's a bit shaky to call this an Eclipse ***bug***.  To be sure, however, it is a surprising characteristic of the Eclipse environment, and one of which I was not previously aware.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So can you please point where this behavior can be changed? It is bugging me for a long time.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't say it could be changed, nor that it was desirable, only that there is a plausible argument for it being conforming (i.e. technically not buggy).

Comment: I believe it was filed as a bug like *years* ago. And since it is not conforming user expectations, I guess we can call it a bug at least from usability point of view. Anyway, it's just semantics..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that there is quirk with the program displaying your output and how it buffers lines. Most outputs will buffer and display per line (that is your output will be saved up until a `\n` char is seen). To fix this you can either force the command to flush with `fflush(stdout)`, or you can change how you are viewing the output. This might mean running your program on the command line.